# Changing web.xml <servlet-mapping> in Eclipse has no effect (Eclipse Juno, Tomcat 6)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm very new to Web programming and am trying to write a simple application to collect data from an input form and pass it to a servlet via `HTTPServletRequest`. I know each servlet needs to be mapped to a particular URL inside `web.xml`. My `web.xml` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>InputFormTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>InputForm.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>InputFormTest</display-name>
    <servlet-name>InputFormTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jsp.core.InputFormTest</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InputFormTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InputFormTest</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

InputForm.jsp shows correctly. I've added the InputFormTest servlet using Eclipse's context menu, i.e. New -> Servlet, which has the following code:

```
package jsp.core;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class InputFormTest
 */
public class InputFormTest extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>InputFormTest</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>User inserted: " + request.getParameter("id") + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

**I have two problems:**

1. Firstly, after running the application within Eclipse, I'm getting the following error

   HTTP Status 404 - /InputFormTest

   ---

   type Status report

   message /InputFormTest

   description The requested resource is not available.

   ---

   Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
2. Secondly, changing `<url-pattern>/InputFormTest</url-pattern>` in `web.xml` doesn't influence the above output, which is weird, because I'd assume `message /InputFormTest` should reflect the setting within `web.xml`

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out. As one could guess, the answer is trivial: Eclipse internal browser caches pages.

This means, the page being shown in Eclipse internal browser after running the newly changed project using "Run as -> Run on server" is an old, cached page. It needs to be manually refreshed afterwards. Kind of weird behavior in case of a web-development project. Apart from that, everything works fine - case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the server and server explorer and click on clean.
Try running the application again. I think it will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, this question was already answered by the OP itself. Didn't you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to add on to the answers above:

If you have cleared your server's cache and refreshed your project, and it is still not working, try clearing the cache of the web browser you are on. This was the last step I had to perform to get my updated web xml to work.